# Elements with Attributes in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How do I put JAXB annotations on my bean class (Product) when one element (Books) needs attributes of its own (title and pages)?

Sample Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getProductsv2Response xmlns:ns2="http://sample.targetnamespace.org/">
            <Product price="123" identifier="23423">
                <Book title="Super Cool Book" pages="45"/>
            </Product>
        </ns2:getProductsv2Response>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String identifier;
    @XmlAttribute
    private Double price;
    @XmlElement(name="Book")
    private Book book;

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }
   public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
   }
}
```

**JAXB generated  XML**

```
<Product identifier="123-12" price="500.0">
    <Book title="Test Book" pages="100"/>
</Product>
```